# Split a matlab column into several columns?

Tags: arrays, matlab, split, cell

I have a .txt file that when loaded puts the data:

```
'A:     -379     G:      277 '
'A:     -422     G:      291 '    
'A:     -361     G:      217 '
```

into a single column as a cell, I've tried getting it to work with importdata('.txt''') etc, as well trying other peoples ideas but so far have come up empty handed. Most likely due to not understanding how some of the functions work well enough.

As can probably be guessed I need the data to be sorted into 4 columns so i can access the 2 sets of values as example:

```
 1       2        3        4 <- Column
A:     -379      G:      277
A:     -422      G:      291    
A:     -361      G:      217
```

Comment: Please provide an example of how you expect the strings to be parsed. A `A:` or `A`. Or would you like a `struct`: `data.A = [-379 -422 -361]`

Comment: Tried to do that in an edit, essentially making the structure of A be an array with 4 columns where column #2 and #4 contains the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [textscan](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to solve the parsing.

```
fid = fopen('text_43254785.txt');
data = textscan(fid, '%s%f%s%f', 'Delimiter',' ', 'MultipleDelimsAsOne',1);
fclose(fid);
```

The format specifier is `'%s%f%s%f'`, indicating a row of [strings, number, string, number]. I used `'Delimiter',' ', 'MultipleDelimsAsOne',1` to treat the multiple spaces as a single delimiter. The result is

```
>> data{1}

ans = 

    'A:'
    'A:'
    'A:'

>> data{2}

ans =

  -379
  -422
  -361
```

From this you can probably get on with your project.

**Edit:**
Updated to use pastebin example.

Comment: using that method, data{1} seems to return:
ans =

  0×1 empty cell array

I'll try upload the textfile, might be some unseen issue with it.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0CmkUL5v This is the link to the pastebin which showed me something the .txt file did not, there is a spacing between each set of data. When i loaded this into a new .txt file matlab loaded it as before. Except now the '' seems to be gone.

Comment: So the `'` should be in there? The current answer works with the pastebin example.

Comment: AH! Seems to work now, its just that data returned me a 4x1... where each cell is a 2531x1 double which I think is what I needed. I'll have to try that a bit but I think it works :) but do you have any idea how to.. "unpack" the data into an array now? I'm having a few issues. Still many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textscan`:

```
s = fopen('MPU2.txt', 'r');
data=textscan(s,'%s%d%s%d%*s');
fclose(s);
```

Comment: Can't seem to get that to work.. It returns an 1x4 matrix, doesn't seem to actually save any of the data
Not sure if I'm using the function wrong, 
B= textscan('MPU2.txt','%2s%d%2s%d')

Comment: assumed the data doesn't surrounded by '

Comment: That is one of my problems I'm having, sorry, should have made that more clear.
 
The new code you showed creates an 'array' with a single value, 3, in it, as well as a 1x4 array.

Comment: I tried to make it work, but it didn't seem to work, edited my previous comment to match. Tried Jørgens attempt as well and have uploaded a pastebin of the txt (warning its huge) which i then downloaded as a .txt file again and loaded it, which seemed to remove the '' marks. However I still cannot get any of the code to work.